# Implement the option of choosing product weight on drop down option

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, custom-options, product-list

[image: Drop down product choose]

I Would like the same exact option shown in the image to implement on my site. how can it be done

Comment: try this link: http://www.magesolution.com/blog/techniques-show-product-options-in-product-list/

Comment: Looks like a configurable attribute. Add it, make your products use it

Comment: @RobbieAverill your correct the products do need to be configurable but the screenshot is from the product listing page and not the product detail page. Showing the configurable options is not native within Magento hence the reason for extra work.

Answer (score -1):

I have used this [multi add](http://www.shaliraweb.com/magento-extensions/add-multiple-products-to-cart-with-custom-options-and-configurable-products.html) extension before and it seems to do exactly what you want and more

Comment: Not sure why I have a minus?